# Kafka Messaging Not Working

Tags: apache-kafka, jhipster

I was trying to setup the message as per example documentation. All my services and classes are decorated with the Component or Service annotation, yet I am still getting the following exception:

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'

The application setup has been augmented with: 
    cloud:
        stream:
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: localhost
                    zk-nodes: localhost
            bindings:
                subscribableChannel:
                    destination: matrics
                messageChannel:
                    destination: matrics
                    content-type: application/json

thanks for any help/pointer-

best regards-

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found out that the issue was not a mis-configuration of spring cloud messaging but rather an ordering issue of the code execution: i.e. my code sending the messages executed before spring cloud had the time to set up the kafka channels.

Using the SmartLifeCycle interface I was able to make sure that the code executed after the initialization and it now works fine-

The error message threw me off as it seemed to indicate a configuration issue.